# how to use sbt/amm scala script on pipe operator?

Tags: scala, sbt, ammonite, scala-script

I want to deal with log output with scala script. Like this:
`java -jar app.jar | log.sc` or `java -jar app.jar | amm log.sc`
How to write a `log.sc` deal with `app.jar` print logs?

### motivation

Replace `java -jar app.jar > app.log` with some smarter way to handle the output stream.
From now on, I want save the output stream to different file by days.

Thanks.

#### UPDATE

think of this example:

```
object Main extends App {
  var i = 0L
  while(true) {
    println("hello " + i)
    i += 1
  }
}
```

it assembly to a `Loop.jar`, how can I deal with printing log to file by date?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the call to java inside your Ammonite script.

`val log = %%('java,"-jar","app.jar")`

The log variable captures the output and you can have the script write it a named logged file.

You can see an example where I do something similar [here](https://github.com/FourMInfo/DevOps/blob/master/gitStuff.sc). There is an included script from [another repository](https://github.com/FourMInfo/Common) where I create & name the log file.

Comment: `app.jar` is a massive web project. `val log` shouldn't hold the result in memory.It seems caused a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception.Could you write some example?

Comment: The way I understood it originally is that you wanted to capture the terminal output when you launch the app, which is what I was suggesting above. But from your example you have this app which is doing quite a bit of output which you want to capture. It seems to me, Ammonite isn't what you want. This sounds like a classic logging use case, and you should investigate the many good options for handling logging in Java/Scala like slf4j with for example this [Scala wrapper](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging)